# Organization chart algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graphics, charts, drawing2d

Does anyone have a line on an algorithm to place boxes in an organizational chart?
Any language is fine.

Comment: What is organizational chart?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are doing and what you are wanting to do?  What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?  You will get a much better response if you post your existing code so that we have something to start from.

Comment: An organizational chart is a graph that graphically shows a hierarchy, such as a company's pecking order (i.e. president, vp, directors, managers, etc)

Comment: I will code it ultimately in ActionScript 3, but any language would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

[yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html) might be of interest.  I've not used it, though I have some experience of yEd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel.  I did that for a family tree once, which is similar to an org chart.